# can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `ClassName`

Tags: c++, linux, g++

Есть класс `ClassName` который определен в динамической библиотеке, и который используется в исполняемом файле. Во время выполнения возникает ошибка

> can't find linker symbol for virtual table for 'ClassName'

Что это за ошибка? Насколько я понимаю все символы должны разрешится на этапе линковки. В чем может быть причина?

Не могу привести пример, воспроизводящий проблему, потому что не понятна причина появления ошибки.

Comment: Возможно, отсутствует определение какой-то виртуальной функции, например, деструктора.

Comment: Это не ошибка времени выполнения, это ошибка времени линковки. А возникает она по многим причинам, например, потому что используется gcc для линковки, а не  g++.

Comment: Это ошибка возникает именно во время работы приложения

Comment: а Вы держите классы в so файле и используете их в основном приложении?

Comment: @KoVadim Да классы реализованы в динамической библиотеке, есть базовый класс c чисто виртуальной функцией и производный в котором эта функция определена, деструктор виртуальный. Ругается именно на производный класс

Comment: собственно Вы и ответили на свой вопрос. В студии под винду есть хаки, как такое сделать, под линукс-gcc мне не известно

Comment: @KoVadim а можно немного поподробней пожалуйста, я что-то не очень понял, это же обычная ситуация которую я описал, причем здесь хаки?

Comment: перенос объектов через границу динамическая библиотека <-> бинарь не очень обычная ситуация.

Comment: @Rikitikitavi, изолировать проблему до минимального примера, я так понимаю, не получается? всё (и библиотеку и бинарь) пересобрать не забыл сразу? пока без примера что-то предсказать вряд ли получится... чисто умозрительно, есть две чисто гипотетические версии: 1)либа была собрано с нормальной реализацией виртуального класса, потом был собран бинарный файл, а потом либа была пересобрана без реализации потомка... 2) проблемы из-за какого-то странного использования `rtti`'я.

Comment: @KoVadim, ситуация звучит как вполне обычная: импорт структуры классов из динамической библиотеки... или я чего-то очевидного не замечаю?

Comment: да собственно все и описали. Слишком много постоянно нужно подгонять, что бы оно как то работало.